# pam_authenticate error, doas problem

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, pam, github

I wanted to try doas (https://github.com/slicer69/doas) I have done everything thats on github page but when I try to use doas it gave me this error

```
doas: pam_authenticate: Permission denied
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Did you read the note under install for Linux? Note to Linux users: Some Linux distributions, such as CentOS, will block doas from using PAM authentication by default. If this happens, it is usually possible to work around the issue by running the following command as the administrator:

  cp /etc/pam.d/sudo /etc/pam.d/doas

Comment: I did, but I dont run centOS I use LTS of ubuntu

Comment: I says such as not only. Please follow the instructions.

Comment: I run the command it worked, thank you

Comment: I made it an answer please accept Up votes are nice but accept is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the documentation for the install of this app for Linux based systems, in this case Ubuntu you must do the following:

> Note to Linux users: Some Linux distributions, such as CentOS, will
> block doas from using PAM authentication by default. If this happens,
> it is usually possible to work around the issue by running the
> following command as the administrator: cp /etc/pam.d/sudo
> /etc/pam.d/doas.

CentOS is only uses as an example.

Answer (score 0):

cp /etc/pam.d/sudo /etc/pam.d/doas